# Wrong behavior li-ion battery charger

Tags: pcb, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.circuitsdiy.com/projects/usb-li-ion-charger/) to build a li-ion battery charger circuit, I made two circuits (the last one better than the first), but any of them works as expected.

Schematics (I copied from the page above):
[image]

Board:
[image]

The circuit:
[image]
[image]

- LED 1 (the one in middle) works as expected (glows if battery or
  usb is connected)
- LED 2 (the one above LED 1) flashes every time (not sure if should flash when battery is disconnected)
- LED 3 never turns on (should glow if battery is full or if battery is absent)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Apart from possible errors, this is as the original says, a "LiIon battery" charger. It is not intended to charge "USB input devices. You may perhaps be connecting a LiIon battery directly to the USB socket at the output, but this is not obvious. Are you?

Comment: Im using the mini USB as power input and the female USB as output to charge a 18650 Li-ion battery

Comment: See updates to my answer. Some of my comments about Green LED Vfs were wrong - now corrected.

Comment: Re transistor pinout. The datasheet I found had it as EBC when viewed as shown. Collector must go to output. IF pinout of your part is CBE when viewed as per my diagram then it is OK. BUT my comments about LED Vf would still apply.

Answer (score 2):

- List item

A word of advice: scrap it ASAP. This thing can be dangerous.

For debugging:

- measure voltage across R2
- measure voltage across R3
- measure voltage across R4

From the circuit LED2 is supposed to be flashing during charging.

EDIT: forget the comment system, this is far better.

- the transistor used is not strong enough
- please keep in mind that the RED LED forward voltage can vary by as much as 15% from LED to LED at room temperature
- please note also the temperature coeficient of the forward voltage: 2.1mV / C
- TL431 would work, why the TLV then?

Comment: T1 is also probably flipped around? I am looking at a datasheet showing the collector is the highest pin when looking at the circuit from top to bottom.

Comment: Check that T1 is on the top layer in Eagle. If it's on bottom layer you assembled it wrong.

Comment: it would be a shame to scrap every device that used low cost or available parts to competently address an application usually only served by custom ICs. Take due care? Certainly. Dangerous? Potentially, yes. But if used with an appreciation of worst case outcomes some good learning could happen - for any of the possible outcomes :-).

Comment: Got that right :)

Comment: Or replace a certain diode with a TL413, adjust two transistors, add series resistance (as the USB usually does not have current limiting) and have a circuit that is trully safe. but it certainly would loose some educational potential :)

Comment: according to the datasheet I've read http://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/433165/MCC/S8550-D/54/1/S8550-D.html the S8550-D is a PNP CBE transistor and  I used "2N4126-PNP-TO92-CBE (*-PNP-)" on eagle schematic, everything is on the bottom layer, should I flip the transistor?

Comment: I'd say yes. It seems to me it is not correctly assembled.

Comment: The transistor you are using only carries up to 200mA of current. Standard USB can supply up to 500mA.

Comment: I do not know if you two can read this, but there is also the issue with the transistor used being runned over specs. TL431 would work OK, why do you want to go the TLV route?

Comment: @Iggy  - I only saw your TL4xx comment after I had posted similar. We are thinking along the same lines. Your TL413 should read TL431 and it needs to be TLV431 (1.25V (1.24)) OR adjust resistors. Hmmm TL431 (or TLV ...) saves two resistors if R2 R3 adjusted to give 2.5V when VBat is correct.

Comment: Comments crossing in the mail :-). TL431 OK (but not TL413 :-) ) . I suggested TLV so he could leave R2 R3 as is BUT there is no point in doing so. As you suggest - us TL431 and just change one resistor. A modest P channel MOSFET would do nicely for T1. Then ... :-),

Answer (score 0):

T1, the 8550D is reversed, as Iggy says.

[8550D datasheet here](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/SS/SS8550.pdf)

You have done a reasonable job with the circuit board and it is a shame to waste it. However, the design has several major flaws. As I commented to Iggy - building a competent design from common parts can be a good learning experience. Unfortunately, this design is not a good one.

R3 & R4 divide the battery voltage in 2 and then compare it to the voltage on LED1. Charging stops when Vbattery is > 2 x V_LED1. For this to work well D1 would need to have a Vf (forward) voltage of EXACTLY 2.1V. Green LEDS typically haave Vfs of about 1.8V to 2.3V but some are even higher. eg [**this one**](http://www.osram-os.com/Graphics/XPic6/00078911_0.pdf) has a Vf of typically 2.6V+ at 3 mA. A LED with the wrong Vf will undercharge or overcharge (and destroy) your battery. Note that he says LED1 = green on his diagram BUT it is RED on his PCB. Red LEDs have similar Vfs to green LEDs.

You COULD replace LED 1 with a reference diode set to EXACTLY 2.1V or less. Eg a TLV431 (NOT a TL431) with 6k8 cathode to reference and 10k reference to ground. Connect Cathode to IC1A pin 2 and anode to ground. Leave R2 in place and remove LED1.

You could instead just choose a LED for LED1 that has Vf = 2.1V (or slightly less).
Then charge the battery and monitor it's voltage. If charging stops at Vbattery < 4.2V note what the voltage is. If charging does not stop at Vbattery = 4.2V measure the voltages at IC1A pin 2 and pin 3. Then stop the charging so that your battery is not damaged. Vpin 3 will have been lower than Vpin2 (or charging would have stopped. You can adjust R3 by soldering a larger value R in parallel until charging stops when Vbattery reaches 4.2V.

The end point battery will vary with temperature. Slightly lower is OK. Slightly higher may destroy your battery.

A second flaw with the design is that it stops as soon as Vbattery = Vmax. This gives the battery a long life (if Vmax <= 4.2V) BUT lowers the energy that the battery receives per charge by about 20 to 30%. If you are happy with that the battery will last longer BUT Vmax MUST NOT exceed 4.2V.

[image]